creating a window in swift using Cocoa
I want to create a class that I can use to create a window in Cocoa Swift. I want to be able to call the styleMasking. Also I'm not using XCode because I want to understand Swift development separately from XCode.
Here is my code:
import Cocoa

class customWindow {
    var size: [Double]
    var position: [Double]
    let window: NSWindow!

    init(size: [Double], position: [Double], title: String, styleMasking: NSWindow.StyleMask) {
        self.size = size
        self.position = position

        window = NSWindow(contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size[0], height: self.size[1]), styleMask: styleMasking, backing: .buffered, defer: true)
        window.title = title

        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(size: [100, 100], position: [0, 0], title: "Untitled", styleMasking: [.closable, .titled, .resizable, .miniaturizable])
    }
}

var myWindow: customWindow = customWindow()

When I run my code no error pops up, but the window doesn't display. Also the code runs, but it never completes
I've tried playing around with the window init. I've changed the position to test if it was just being created off screen. I've played with the width and height.
I also moved removed the window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil) and changed the defer to both true and false, and the code completed instead of continuing to run, but the window didn't show up again.
I also tried calling the customWindow my initializing it using the init instead of the convenience init but with all the same properties, and it ran and completed, but didn't display the window. This leads me to believe it is a problem with the calling of the class, but I could be wrong.

You need to create an NSApp, and run() it. This article is written in Objective C, but the general idea is exactly what you're looking for: https://cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/minimalist-cocoa-programming.html This one also looks great: https://czak.pl/2015/09/23/single-file-cocoa-app-with-swift.html

Also, lowerCamelCase names are used for variables and values in Swift. Type names should be UpperCamelCase, like CustomWindow.

@Alexander How would create an NSApp and run it. I'm new to swift.

My answer already explain that. Look below.

You need to configure an NSApp and run() it.
import Cocoa

class CustomWindow {
    let size: [Double]     // These are never changed... should they be 'let'?
    let position: [Double] // These are never changed... should they be 'let'?
    let window: NSWindow! // A "Window" contains a window... that's a little odd.

    init(size: [Double], position: [Double], title: String, styleMasking: NSWindow.StyleMask) {
        self.size = size
        self.position = position

        window = NSWindow(contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size[0], height: self.size[1]), styleMask: styleMasking, backing: .buffered, defer: true)
        window.title = title

        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(size: [100, 100], position: [0, 0], title: "Untitled", styleMasking: [.closable, .titled, .resizable, .miniaturizable])
    }
}

let myWindow: CustomWindow = CustomWindow()

NSApplication.shared // Sets the value of `NSApp`
NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.regular)
NSApp.run()

